# Woocommerce hook usage for custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Just want to know how my current hood usage is not working?

eg I am trying to output my html after the single product page product description. However nothing displays. I am pretty sure I got the correct hook from the reference.

Thanks

```
function plugin_output() {
loadAssets();
$html = '
      <div id="product-configurator">
        <div id="configurator-menu-items">
          <div id="appLogo">
            <img src="'.plugins_url("/product-configurator/app_logo.png").'" alt="Shades By Us" />
          </div>
          <div id="configurator-tab1" class="configurator-tab" data-page="configurator-panel1">Shape</div>
          <div id="configurator-tab2" class="configurator-tab" data-page="configurator-panel2">Size</div>
          <div id="configurator-tab3" class="configurator-tab" data-page="configurator-panel3">Color</div>
          <div id="configurator-variables" class="variables-current">
            <p class="variables-title">Your Selection</p>
            <ul>
              <li class="configurator-variables">Shape: <span id="current_model"></span></li>
              <li class="configurator-variables">Colors: </li>
              <li class="configurator-variables">Size: </li>
              <li class="configurator-variables">Quantity: </li>
              <li class="configurator-variables">Total Price: </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="configurator-panels">
          <div class="configurator-panel" id="configurator-panel1">
            <canvas class="product-canvas"></canvas>
            <div id="defaultModels">
              <div class="modelBtn modelBtn1" id="model1"></div>
              <div class="modelBtn modelBtn2" id="model2"></div>
              <div class="modelBtn modelBtn3" id="model3"></div>
              <div class="modelBtn modelBtn4" id="model4"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="configurator-panel" id="configurator-panel2">
            <canvas class="product-canvas"></canvas>
            <div id="sizeSelection">
              <div class="sizeSelector" id="selectorSize1">
                <ul>
                  <li class="sizeSelectTitle">Bottom</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeBottom" id="size1">T 30 / 8 40</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeBottom" id="size2">T 40 / 8 50</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeBottom" id="size3">T 50 / 8 60</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeBottom" id="size4">T 70 / 8 80</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="sizeSelector" id="selectorSize2">
                <ul>
                  <li class="sizeSelectTitle">Height</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeHeight" id="size5">30 cm</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeHeight" id="size6">40 cm</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeHeight" id="size7">50 cm</li>
                  <li class="sizeSelect sizeHeight" id="size8">70 cm</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="configurator-panel" id="configurator-panel3">
            <canvas class="product-canvas"></canvas>
          </div>
          <a id="next-btn-configurator" onclick="">Move On</a>
        </div>
      </div>
';
return $html;
}
add_shortcode("product-configurator", "plugin_handler");
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'plugin_output' );
```

Comment: You need to use `add_action()` instead of `do_action()`. And `echo` the resulting `$html` instead of `return` it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
function plugin_output() {
    loadAssets();
    $html = 'content here...';
    echo $html;
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'plugin_output');
```

Note use of add_action() instead of do_action().

The same applies to filter hooks, except that you would return value from your handler:

```
function my_handler($value) {

    // Do something with $value here...

    return $value;
}
add_filter('some_filter_hook', 'my_handler');
```